# Multiple login pages for different claims

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is my situation.

To do some actions on the web site user should be authenticated. Different actions require different claims. For example, to make an order user is authenticated by phone number only, to view the purchase history user should be authenticated by phone number and password, and to change the phone number user should be authenticated using two-factor authentication.

I create a login page for each of the authentication methods and when user is authenticated I give her a set of claims depending on the authentication method.
I add `[Authorize(Policy="CanCreateOrder")]` to the `CreateOrder` action method. The policy has the logic what claims required to authorize user. In case user is not authorized I want to redirect the user to the appropriate login page.

The question is how I could specify the url where user should be redirected for authentication?

Looking at `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` I could not see how to to specify login page depending on what claims required. Documentation suggests to set `LoginPath` property at the configuration time, but in my case login url depends on what claims I need to authorize the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use different authentication scheme for each different claim:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Phone",
    LoginPath = "<phone - path>"
    ....
}

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Password",
    LoginPath = "<password - path>"
    ....
}

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "TwoFactor",
    LoginPath = "<twofactor - path>",
    ....
}
```

And then usage:

```
[Authorize(Policy="CanCreateOrder", ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Phone")]
```

Also you can use multiple scheme:

```
[Authorize(Policy="CanCreateOrder", ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Phone,TwoFactor")]
```

See https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme.html

Comment: With the example `[Authorize(Policy="CanCreateOrder", ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Phone,TwoFactor")]` how it is decided where the user will be redirected in case the policy failed? "<twofactor - path>" or "<phone - path>"?

Comment: If one of the schemes is successful, the user will be authenticated. Otherwise  the user will be redirected the last one scheme's path(TwoFactor).

Answer (score 1):

From aspnet core 2, use can use the attribute for the controller, action o razor page you need to configure:

```
[Authorize(Policy="CanCreateOrder")]
```

Configure your policy with the authenticationscheme

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CanCreateOrder",
                  authBuilder =>
                  {
                    authBuilder.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Management_Scheme");
                    authBuilder.RequireClaim("Manager");
                  });
    });
    ...
}
```

and multiple cookie authentication configuration depending on the authentication scheme:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("Public_Scheme" , options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
            })
           .AddCookie("Management_Scheme",options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/management/login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/management/logout";
            });
    ...
}
```

This extensions must be used inside `ConfigureServices` method and not `Configure`.

Take into account that configuring the authentiucation scheme inside the policy is not mandatory, it can be can addes to the authorization attribute wherever needed:

```
[Authorize("CanCreateOrders",AuthenticationSchemes = "ManagementScheme")]
```

You can see more about migrating in to 2.0 [in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x).

Answer (score 0):

This Is Perfect, The method I use for two different login authorizations

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = false;
        }).
            AddCookie("CustomSchema1",
            options =>
       {
           options.Cookie.Name = "CustomCookieName1";
           options.LoginPath = "/login";
           options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
           options.SlidingExpiration = true;
       }).AddCookie("CustomSchema2", options =>
         {
             options.Cookie.Name = "CustomCookieName2";
             options.LoginPath = "/writer/login";
             options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
             options.SlidingExpiration = true;
         });
```