# Is it possible to support multiple Login Path identity in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-3.1

> I am using identity in Asp.net Core 3.0. I have two login pages like `(/Account/AdminLogin)` and `(/Account/UserLogin)` And two roles `Admin` and `User`.

> My issue is that when I use `[Authorize]` tag into the controller when session out it return to me in `(/Account/AdminLogin)` page because it's set on `startup` file.

> For `Admin` login it should be after logout URL `(/Account/AdminLogin)`

> For `User` login it should be after logout URL `(/Account/UserLogin)`

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
                {
                    // Cookie settings  
                    options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/AdminLogin";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; 
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the `OnRedirectToLogin` event on the options.
Something like this

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings  
    options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/UserLogin";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; 
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        if (IsAdminContext(context))
        {
            var redirectPath = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
            context.Response.Redirect("/Account/AdminLogin" + redirectPath.Query);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

In `IsAdminContext` you need to distinguish if for the given request you want to forward the user to the normal user login or to the admin login. A possible implementation could look like this. Where for all urls starting with /admin you would forward to the admin login.

```
private static bool IsAdminContext(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
{
    return context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/admin");
}
```

Comment: This is not a good approach sometime we have not getting contains URL like /admin. In that case this approach is failed.

Comment: Based on what criteria can you distinguish what login to show? The user is not logged in yet, so it needs to be based on something else. What could be used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48864174/10988372 I think this is better solution

Comment: yes, if you want to have completely separate schemas that might work better for you. In your example you don't show whether you use a specific policy or not and whether this is needed or not. Will leave my answer as a possible approach

Comment: Your Answer is also good but I don't want to write more conditions (Controller) like StartsWithSegments("/admin") || StartsWithSegments("/account") .....