# .NET Core Cookie Authentication - controlling AccessDenied, Login and Logout paths for different types of users - how?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have inherited an old .Net Framework 4 website that we would like to update to .NET core.  The website has two types of users - "regular" and "admin".

The "regular" users account home page and login / logout paths are:

```
/user/account/
/user/login/
/user/logout/
```

The "admin" users account home page and login / logout paths are:

```
/admin/account/
/admin/login/
/admin/logout/
```

The current site **creates a separate cookie (distinct cookie name) for each type of user**.

Using .NET Core, my understanding is that when using cookie-based authentication, only a single cookie can be created, something along the lines of:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme ).AddCookie( opts =>
{

   opts.Cookie.Name = "user_auth";

   opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/user/login/";

   opts.LoginPath = "/user/login/";

   opts.LogoutPath = "/user/logout/";

} );
```

... and we cannot include another "AddAuthentication" (cookie) by doing the following:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme ).AddCookie( opts =>
{

   opts.Cookie.Name = "admin_auth";

   opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/admin/login/";

   opts.LoginPath = "/admin/login/";

   opts.LogoutPath = "/admin/logout/";

} );
```

I could consolidate the login process to use a single cookie and grant "user" and "admin" roles/claims at login, but my question is how then does one control or set the "AccessDeniedPath", "LoginPath" and "LogoutPath" depending on the role / claims in use?

My feeling is that one cannot, and we will have to do "manual" checking instead of using [Authorize] attributes with policies, i.e.:

```
[Authorize( Policy = "user" )]
```

... if the above fails, the user would be redirected to the "AccessDeniedPath" -- correct for the "user" role, but would be incorrect for:

```
[Authorize( Policy = "admin" )]
```

... as the "admin" user would be redirect to a "user" login path.

I am hoping to find a way to redirect users to a different login/logout/denied paths based on a policy or role.

Looking for insights on how others have tackled this type of issue (different cookie names for different types of users) in legacy sites being "upgraded" to .NET Core.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found - the trick is to use two different scheme names.

The following posts lead me to the solution:

- [Is it possible to support multiple Login Path identity in .net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751686/is-it-possible-to-support-multiple-login-path-identity-in-net-core)
- [Multiple login pages for different claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383303/multiple-login-pages-for-different-claims/48864174)

The following code snippets may help as well:

Setup authentication service using two schemes ("users" and "admins") / cookies:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddCookie( "users", cookie_users_auth_options_set )
   .AddCookie( "admins", cookie_admins_auth_options_set );
```

... and then configure the cookie options.

The user cookie options:

```
public static void cookie_users_auth_options_set( CookieAuthenticationOptions opts )
{

   opts.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString( "/account/login/" );

   opts.LoginPath = new PathString( "/account/login/" );

   opts.LogoutPath = new PathString( "/account/logout/" );

   opts.Cookie.Name = "user_auth";

   opts.Cookie.Path = "/";

}
```

The admin cookie options:

```
public static void cookie_admins_auth_options_set( CookieAuthenticationOptions opts )
{

   opts.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString( "/admin/login/" );

   opts.LoginPath = new PathString( "/admin/login/" );

   opts.LogoutPath = new PathString( "/admin/logout/" );

   opts.Cookie.Name = "admin_auth";

   opts.Cookie.Path = "/";

}
```

Then, handlers / methods for users can be decorated with the [Authorize] attribute as follows:

```
[Authorize( AuthenticationSchemes = "users", Policy = "whatever" )]
```

.. and handlers / methods for admins can be decororated as follows:

```
[Authorize( AuthenticationSchemes = "admins", Policy = "whatever" )]
```

... handlers / methods for users and admins:

```
[Authorize( AuthenticationSchemes = "admins, users", Policy = "whatever" )]
```

Or.. one can check "manually" within a method using:

- [AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.authenticateasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-authenticationhttpcontextextensions-authenticateasync(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpcontext-system-string))
- [ChallengeAsync(HttpContext, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.challengeasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-authenticationhttpcontextextensions-challengeasync(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httpcontext-system-string))